# iso-8859-1 vs utf-8 android

Tags: android, encoding

I have an object in retriving http post response from webserver. However unicode will requires me to do the following

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
```

instead of my usual

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
```

If i were to use unicode for all response, will it affect my normal text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sould check what the webserver responses. It can be iso-8859-1 or UTF-8. Check the Charset of the [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header from the HTTP response